# Glass BSDF shows weird black lines after sculpting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, sculpting, glass

I decided to make an ice cube. It looked good on the default cube, but i knew that if i sculpt it, it would look a lot better. So i made another cube and i went into sculpting mode (It was my first time doing any sculpting, thought that its going to be easy). So after looking at what the different brushed do, i decided that to make what i need i will use the smooth brush on the edges of the cube. So after some work i made something i liked. But then on the next day, i saw these black things after i removed my bump map (it used a noise texture to give the ice some good look) - they were really weird.

[image]

[image]

I thought its something from the new roughness map i used, but after removing it from the roughness it was still there. Then in solid mode i saw the shading issues.

[image]

Here is the wireframe of the object: [image]

But after one subdivision modifier it was ok in solid, but still weird in rendered mode. I am using cpu rendering, cause my gpu gives Split render kernel errors. Here is my current node setup, just the glass.

[image]

Comment: Can you check Face Orientation view to see if some normals are flipped?  The entire object surface should be colored blue in that view.

Comment: @AllenSimpson its all blue, also tried with backface culling, shows that its all fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a [*Solidify Modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) and add thickness to the cube. Do bear in mind, this does essentially double the geometry calculated at render, so this might increase render time some.

---

This is the result from your file:

[image]

Comment: Man, that worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, no. Now i see that its still pretty dead [image](https://imgur.com/a/aimqB6t). Even with solidify, a subdiv, and no auto smooth. I kind of think that it may be because its looking broken in solid mode as well, but i cant be too sure. Or i did something with the solidify modifier wrong?

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209  nope, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyj7q.jpg) is what it looks like here..

Comment: wow, this is weird. What version are you using?

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 the file was opened in 2.91.0

Comment: soo, i am in the same version. I decided to make a new material and use only the glass bsdf, so there arent any unused  nodes floating around, but its still broken. Even applying the modifiers didnt work.

Comment: Can you please send me the .blend file, which you used for the photo? I start to think that maybe i am doing something wrong with the modifier and maybe you did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In The Properties > Object Data Properties > Normals >

Make sure 'Auto Smooth' is unchecked.

Comment: Just tried it, still the same.

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 Try disabling one Modifier at a time see which one changes the render. If there is no help try adding a wireframe image or send the Blend file.

Comment: There isnt much to disable, just one subdiv. So, here is the link: [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ahajcbc8otoEZiepuFc5zVgUmXXpPzgf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hmm. Disabling autosmooth appeared to solve the problem for me. Maybe look again without subsurf?